# extractText returns blank text

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I have followed the documentation, getIsEncrypted and other attribute is working but extractText() shows blank str.

```py
import PyPDF2 as pPDF

def extract_pdf(): 
    pdf_file_pointer = open('example/pdf/sample.com', 'rb')
    pdf_file_obj = pPDF.PdfFileReader(pdf_file_pointer)

    page_1 = pdf_file_obj.getPage(1)
    print(page_1.extractText())

extract_pdf()
```

Here is a link of pdf file I am working. I want to extract text of the pdf. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b8M0fuI1GV1zeDYWqIcA1vCcLghb4gXm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am having the same problem, however in my case the return value is '\n\n\n\n\n'

Comment: Please try [this library](https://pypi.org/project/tika/) . From my experience this is the best library to read pdf. Only drawback is that you need Java to use it.

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 received lots of improvements in 2022.
Additionally, the project moved back to pypdf.

Upgrade your code and likely it will work :-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will give pypdf a shot in next projects.  